# Shell script for installing latest stable version of CherryPy

Tags: shell, cherrypy

I am trying to write a shell script for installing the latest stable version of CherryPy without hardcoding the version number. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `easy_install` or `pip` to grab it from the [Cheeseshop](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/CherryPy/3.2.2)? That should automatically install the latest stable version.

If you need a wrapper around calling `pip` or `easy_install` (eg, because you are installing into a *virtualenv*, or to some non-global path, etc) then write an ity-bitty shell script to make the call correctly. It should be quite simple.